# Access Services and SharePoint 2010 - Need Info

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010

I've been asked to research the ability to publish Access solutions directly to SharePoint as demonstrated in the demo below.

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Access/Microsoft-Access-2010-Demo/

I'm going to keep searching via Google / Bing - but I thought I'd check here to see if anyone has any good links to information on this feature.  At first glance it seems like I'm getting alot of brief blog entries with links to the SP2009 conference or to the above video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's some excellent discussion happening with Albert Kallal and others on this topic in the newsgroups.  See my [blog postings on the topic of SharePoint and Access 2010](http://msmvps.com/blogs/access/archive/tags/SharePoint/default.aspx).   I've given you a link to the SharePoint tags as I will be blogging any additional discussions in the newsgroups using that tag.  So keep checking back every week or two.

Also I believe Access 2010 is now available as a public beta this week so you can download some or all of it yourself.   Visit Technet/MSDN.

Comment: Thanks - the newsgroup discussions should yield some useful information.

Comment: @Tony! If my PC hadn't been tied up with me trying to run too many apps, I was going to post that!

Comment: David <chuckle>  well, I might as well get the points on this one anyhow, eh?

Answer (score 0):

This site is in beta, [Access Hosting](http://www.accesshosting.com)
. I can't speak for he quality of their service (Hosting Windows Server, SharePoint, SQL Server), but they have several tutorials and other information on publishing Accesss 2010 apps on SharePoint. Their service is free for trial and they have not posted any pricing that I could find.