# how do i build a website using access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

has anyone done this yet? please show me some good tutorials on building websites with databases using ACCESS 2010

you can build a website using it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Comment: They're still making new versions of that? Why would you want to use it over a proper database server?

Comment: *cries a little* I don't suppose we could encourage you to use SQLServer Express, SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL instead? (all free options)

Comment: A *website* using Access 2010? How is that even possible?

Comment: @jenny - I agree with the above comments - please checkout one of the more robust databases like SQLServer Express, SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL - Access is not meant to really be used this way - even though you can.

Comment: I think none of the four people so far posting comments paid any attention at all to the rollout of Access 2010, which, via Sharepoint, provides a host of very robust new features that allow you to use Access to develop and deploy web applications. The data is stored in Sharepoint, not in Jet/ACE, but I'm not even certain the degree of sophistication of these three comments indicate an intellectual potential to even comprehend the distinction. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752154/access-services-and-sharepoint-2010-need-info

Comment: Some silly comments here. When you publish an access application to the web it based on the cloud computing (SharePoint) platform. The end result is scalability out to millions of users for ONE site! Access forms when published become XAML forms (.net zammel forms). (google .net + xaml if you don't know what this means). Access reports when published to the web become report definition languages (RDL), and are rendered using SQL server reporting services.  In fact, you can open up the resulting access web forms using .net VS tools if you want.